# ZFS incremental snapshot send/recv without first snapshot

Tags: zfs, snapshot

I have the following ZFS dataset:

```
pool/dataset
pool/dataset@snap1
pool/dataset@snap2
pool/dataset@snap3
```

Which has been replicated to a backup pool, using ZFS send/recv

```
backupPool/dataset
backupPool/dataset@snap1
backupPool/dataset@snap2
```

Afterwards, I deleted `dataset@snap1` and `dataset@snap2` from `pool`, and I am in a situation where I cannot send `dataset@snap3` incrementally to `backupPool`.

Is there a way of solving this situation? For instance, generate a ZFS incremental snapshot between `pool/dataset@snap3` and `backupPool/dataset@snap2` and send it to `backupPool`? Or transfer back `backupPool/dataset@snap2` to `pool`?

I could transfer `pool/dataset@snap3` to a new dataset in `backupPool`, but I really need to keep the "history" of snapshots.

Comment: Do you really need to have a ZFS dataset as a destination for your backups? It makes the whole concept difficult to manage. I have a similar setup for my backups. I just use serialized compressed snapshots with multiple incremental levels.

Comment: Yes, I do need a ZFS dataset with the backup.

Comment: @MartinSugioarto *serialized compressed snapshots with multiple incremental levels* That does leave you vulnerable to losing your backups entirely if you later have a problem with `zfs receive`. One advantage of immediately running `zfs receive ...` is that any issue is known immediately - not with you have to restore.

Comment: Serialized snapshots can be only a problem, if you delete them in wrong order. Level 0 snapshots are most important, of course. The problem with live datasets is that if something accidentally writes to such a dataset, it's a totally different dataset from the logical point of view and you need to roll back. And if you delete a snapshot there, it's also a write access. On the sending side, if you delete a snapshot, all parent snapshots correct their diffs up to the top live filesystem and you lose any connection with you receiving dataset. This method appears very unstable to me.

Comment: Would `rsync` from `pool/dataset@snap3` to `backupPool/dataset` work?  Then create `backupPool/dataset@snap3` from what was `rsync`'d?  Then try applying `pool/dataset@snap4` on `backupPool`?  I'd try that on a copy of `backPool` if possible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think the rsync solution would fail because the UUID of the `backupPool/dataset@snap3` would not match the one from the source (plus the metadata of the rsync'ed files wouldn't be exactly the same as on the source anyway, so even ignoring the UUID check wouldn't solve the problem).  I think you just need to re-send the incrementals and apply them, and be more careful next time not to delete the last one in the chain.

Comment: @Dan I'm pretty sure that's right - but I'm casting about trying things, as this has me stumped. If I'm reading the question properly, the snapshots now only exist on the backup pool, but there's new data in the original pool. How's this:  use `rsync` as I described, make the snapshot `snap3` on the backup pool, then restore from the backup pool to the original. That might work.  Again, I'd try it on spare disks to be sure...

Comment: I subtlely misunderstood the question! @AndrewHenle's approach would work. When sending the new snapshot back to `pool`, you won't be able to do an incremental send, you just have to do a full send from scratch and create a new filesystem. **By the way**, if you deleted `pool/dataset@snap2` to save space, you could try using [bookmarks](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/solaris/ZFSBookmarksWhatFor) on the sending system instead of full snapshots -- they let ZFS know what changed since the last time you did a `send`, without keeping all of the data from that last snapshot around forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Matthew Ahrens, a maintainer of OpenZFS, you can accomplish this by specifying the prior snapshot on the receiving host as the origin [[1]](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/discussions/10325?sort=new#discussioncomment-232840).

> This should be possible today:
>
> ```
> man zfs-receive
> ...
>      zfs receive [-FhMnsuv] [-o origin=snapshot] [-o property=value]
>          [-x property] filesystem|volume|snapshot
>        -o origin=snapshot
>            Forces the stream to be received as a clone of the given snapshot.
>            If the stream is a full send stream, this will create the filesys‐
>            tem described by the stream as a clone of the specified snapshot.
> ```
>
> So in your example, you can do `zfs send apool@snapshot3 | zfs receive -o origin=bpol@snapshot0 bpool/recvd`. Ideally you'd then `zfs promote bool/recvd`, rename it to replace the original and then destroy the old filesystem. In your example, that might be a bit messy since you are talking about the topmost filesystem. Hopefully in practice you have `bpool/fs@snapshot0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your suggestions!

I finally rsynced `pool/dataset@snap3` with `backupPool/dataset@snap2`, deleted the dataset `backupPool/dataset`, and recreated it from `backupPool/dataset`. I was not able to find a better solution to this problem.

The suggestion from Dan was really helpful. Also, to avoid deleting snapshots in the future it is a good practice to [hold them](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gjdfk/index.html).